# Label Caption When Open Dialog

Tags: label, delphi-7, caption

I'm still a beginner using Delphi 7

When I load a VPN config file using `TOpenDialog`, I put the FileName in a `TLabel`, but its Caption displays the complete file path, eg:

```
D:\ConfigVPN\sample.ovpn
```

How can I display just the file name only?

```
sample.ovpn
```

When my application is closed and reopened, how can the Caption be fixed to `sample.ovpn`?

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.loadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  if OpenDialog.Execute then begin
    config:=OpenDialog.FileName;
    Label.Caption:=config;
    uhuy;
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ExtractFileName()` function in the `SysUtils` unit:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  config := ...;
  Label.Caption := ExtractFileName(config);
end;

procedure TForm1.loadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  if OpenDialog.Execute then begin
    config := OpenDialog.FileName;
    Label.Caption := ExtractFileName(config);
    uhuy;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: what mean `config:=...;`?

Comment: You have a `config` variable. Presumably you are saving that value somewhere so you can read it back on app restart without prompting the user again. That is what `config := ...;` represents - whatever code you are using to read the saved value on app start.